Normalization of Algebraic Curves
I'm reading through Simon Donaldson's Riemann Surfaces, and am confused about his construction for normalizing algebraic curves.
He gives the example of normalizing $w^2 - z^2 (1 - z)$, giving the associated map to $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$ of $\tau \mapsto [1, 1 - \tau^2, \tau - \tau^3]$.
I vaguely understand that this is given by considering the "tangent" $y/x$, which is used to distinguish the two branches of the self intersection at $z = 0$. Is there a general procedure for understanding these maps?

This can be done algebraically using what is called the integral closure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_element#Integral_closure

As @red_trumpet mentions, you should read about blowing up a point (sometimes called the monoidal transform). Start with doing examples of blowing up the origin in $\Bbb C^2$. :)

Suppose $C \subset\mathbb P^2$ is a singular curve of degree $\deg C = d$, and let $f=0$ be the equation defining $C$. Given a point $P=(p,q) \in \mathbb P^2$ (I use affine coordinates for convenience) on $C$ you can always write
$$f(X,Y) = f_0 +  f_1(X-p, Y-q) + f_2(X-p,Y-q) + \dotsb +f_d(X-p,Y-q)$$
where for each $i$ the polynomial $f_i$ is homogeneous of degree $i$. The multiplicity of $P$ on $C$ is defined as the smallest number $k$ such that $f_k \neq 0$. So $P \in C$ iff the multiplicity is $\geq 1$, and $P$ is a singular point on $C$ iff the mulitplicity is $\geq 2$.
Now suppose $P$ is a point of multiplicity $d-1$. Then by Bezout's theorem, each line $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ through $P$ intersects $C$ in exactly one other point $Q(L)$ (possibly $Q(L) = P$, which happens if $L$ is a singular tangent to $C$ at $P$). The set of lines through $P$ is naturally a $\mathbb P^1$, given by
$$\mathbb P^1 \ni [s:t] \mapsto L_{[s:t]} = \{s(X-p) + t(Y-q) = 0\},$$
and this defines a map
$$\mathbb P^1 \to C, \quad [s:t] \mapsto Q(L_{[s:t]}).$$
This is the normalization and proves that every curve $C$ of degree $d$ with a point of multiplicity $d-1$ is rational. In particular every singular cubic is rational, and I guess (check this!) that this should give the normalization written down by Donaldson.
For more complicated curves, I think writing down the normalization explicitly is more difficult, because even writing down the smooth curve is more complicated if it is not a $\mathbb P^1$. There is the algebraic way to do it using the integral closure (see the comment by Qiaochu Yuan). Alternatively you can blow-up $\mathbb P^2$ at the singular points, and if you do this sufficiently often, you get a smooth curve as strict transform, which is the normalization.
